# Allow FTP for user1 and FTPS for user2 in ubuntu

Tags: ftp, sftp, vsftpd, ftps

Is this possible to allow FTP protocol for user1 and use FTPS for user2 in Ubuntu 18.04?

I'm using **vsftpd** with the following configuration

```
listen=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
pam_service_name=vsftpd
ssl_enable=YES
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
allow_writeable_chroot=YES

pasv_enable=YES
pasv_address=SOME_IP_HERE
pasv_addr_resolve=YES

force_local_data_ssl=YES
force_local_logins_ssl=YES
ssl_tlsv1=YES
ssl_sslv2=NO
ssl_sslv3=NO
require_ssl_reuse=NO
ssl_ciphers=HIGH
pasv_min_port=40000
pasv_max_port=50000
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you should run 2 instances of vsftpd then configure one for FTP and the other one for FTPS.

I think requirements should be to get more than 1x network interface.
Here's a nice tutorial from RedHat on how to use multiple instances.

https://access.redhat.com/solutions/5172631

Then you'll need to reconfigure your vsftpd.conf file for every instance